# What it is called when a mother has sexual desires towards her son?

Tags: abnormal-psychology, parenting, sexuality, psychoanalysis

I know about Oedipus complex.

- What is it called when a mother has sexual desires towards her son?
- Is the term reserved for single mothers or does it include married mothers?

Answer (score 7):

[Jocasta complex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jocasta_complex) syndrome is what you are referring to.

> In psychoanalytic analysis, the Jocasta complex is the incestuous
>   sexual desire of a mother towards her son. [SOURCE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jocasta_complex)